# Python if else statement

Tags: python, if-statement

My if statement works but else doesn't can anyone help me?
this is my code. Btw if anyone knows how to ask for a retry after one time would be awesome!

```
import random

print('choose a number between 1 and 10,if you guess right you get 10 points if you guess wrong you lose 15points')

answer = input()

randint = random.randint(0,2)

print('the answer is ',randint)

if [answer == randint]:

 print('gratz! you win 10points!')

else:

 print('you lose 15points!')
```

Comment: This really sounds like homework...

Comment: try deleting [] at if statement.

Comment: `randint` is not a number between 1 and 10...

Answer (score 4):

Don't put brackets around your `if` statement.  When you do that, you are creating a new list.  Change it to this:

```
if answer == randint:
```

You could put parentheses around it if you wanted to, but not `[]`.  Your second problem is that `random.randint()` returns an integer, but `input()` returns a string (in Python3).  You could say `if int(answer) == randint:` instead, or you could say `if answer == str(randint):`.  Your third problem, as @cricket_007 pointed out is `randint(0, 2)` will return an integer between `0` and `2`, not `1` and `10`.  Just change that line to `randint = random.randint(1, 10)`.

Comment: i did but if i do that it only does the else statement this is what i got choose a number between 1 and 10,if you guess right you get 10 points if you guess wrong you lose 15points
1
the answer is  1
you lose 15points!

Comment: xD i knew that but i did 0,2 so i had a higher chance of guessing it right for testing if it works

Comment: That makes sense.  I would probably do that too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to loop after each game, just add these lines around it like so:

```
import random

loop = true

while loop:

      ----insert your code here----
```

This will make it loop endlessly.

Hope this helps!